# How to draw direct graph with tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The function C looks like multiple lines, I want it to have a direct line. How can I make it look one line?
Here is my code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[step=0.5cm,cyan,very thin] (-1,-1) grid (5,6);
            \draw[black, ->] (-1,0) -- (5,0); 
            \draw[black, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,6);
            \draw[thick, black, ->] (0,0) -- (0.5,0); 
            \draw[thick, black, ->] (0,0) -- (0,0.5);
            \draw [scale=0.5, domain=(1/3.65):10,samples=25, teal] plot (\x,{(9+(\x)^2+3*\x)/(3*\x)}) ;
            \draw [scale=0.5, domain=-2:10, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {-2/3*\x+5}); 
            \filldraw[blue] (3,0.5) node[anchor=south] {$d$};
            \filldraw[teal] (4,2) node[anchor=south] {$\mathcal{C}$};
            \filldraw[black] (3,1.75) node[anchor=south west] {A};
            \filldraw[black] (3,1.75) node[] {$\times$};
            \filldraw[black] (0,0.25) node[anchor=east] {$\overrightarrow{i}$};
            \filldraw[black] (0.25,0) node[ anchor=north] {$\overrightarrow{j}$};
            \filldraw[black] (5,0) node[ anchor=south east] {$x$};
            \filldraw[black] (0,6) node[ anchor=north west] {$y$};
            \foreach \x in {-1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
            \draw ({\x cm/2},2pt) -- ({\x cm/2},-2pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
            \foreach \y in {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
            \draw (2pt, {\y cm/2}) -- (-2pt, {\y cm/2}) node[anchor=east]{$\y$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm trying to draw this :
[image]

But I'm getting this :
[image]

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Would you please make your code complete, such that it can be compiled without additional effort?

Comment: Just change `samples=25` to `sample=100`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the samples was 25 instead of 200.

Solution :

```
\draw [scale=0.5, domain=(1/3.65):10,samples=200, teal] plot (\x,{(9+(\x)^2+3*\x)/(3*\x)}) ;
```

Comment: Better to add the `smooth` option here instead of increasing the samples.